# Understanding undetermined coefficients method for system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, systems-of-equations

> Consider the system of differential equations, $$\vec x'=A\vec x+\vec g=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\4 &-2}\vec x+\pmatrix{e^{2t}\\-2e^{t}}\qquad (1)$$ solve this using the method of undetermined coefficients.

I get the eigenvalues $\lambda=-3$ and $2$, and eigenvectors $\vec v=\pmatrix{1\\-4}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\1}$  respectively. So, the general solution is,
$$\vec x_c=C_1\pmatrix{1\\-4}e^{-3t}+C_2\pmatrix{1\\1}e^{2t}$$

Before find a particular solution to $(1)$ let’s rewrite it as,

$$x'=A\vec x+\vec g=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\4 &-2}\vec x+\pmatrix{1\\0}e^{2t}+\pmatrix{0\\-2}e^t$$

We can be split this into two nonhomogeneous equation,

$$
\begin{cases} 
      \vec x'=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\4 &-2}\vec x+\pmatrix{1\\0}e^{2t} & (A) \\
      \vec x'=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\4 &-2}\vec x+\pmatrix{0\\-2}e^t & (B)
   \end{cases}
$$

Let $\vec x_p^{(A)}$ be a particular solution to $(A)$ and $\vec x_p^{(B)}$ be a particular solution to $(B)$. So the general solution to $(1)$ can be written in the form, $$\vec x=\vec x_c+\vec x_p^{(A)}+\vec x_p^{(B)}$$

For $\vec x_p^{(B)}$ I easily manage to get it by using the guess $\vec x=\vec a e^t=\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2}e^t$, $$\vec x_p^{(B)}=\pmatrix{\frac12\\0}e^t$$

But for $\vec x_p^{(A)}$, $\vec x=\vec b e^{2t}=\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}e^{2t}$ guess didn't work. The reason was explained like this:

> Here’s one way of thinking about what just happened. For certain values of $b$ – namely, for $b$ a scalar
> multiple of the eigenvector $\pmatrix{1\\1}-\vec be^{2t}$ is a solution to the associated homogeneous equation. Substituting
> any of these functions into $\vec x'-A\vec x$ gives zero. So substituting an arbitrary function be $\vec be^{2t}$ into $\vec x'-A\vec x$ gives just a one-dimensional space of outputs, where we sort of need a two-dimensional one. If our forcing function was also a scalar multiple of $\pmatrix{1\\1}e^{2t}$, we’d be able to solve for $\vec x$, but in general, this is too little space to move in. Try $\vec x=\vec b te^{2t}+\vec d e^{2t}$ for $\vec x_p^{(A)}$.

To be honest, I didn't understand what the explanation want to say. And how they manage to guess the particular solution form? And another thing is why we need to split $(1)$ into two nonhomogeneous equation $(A),(B)?$ It will be OK if anyone suggest/reference any theorem/analysis answer for me. All I just need to understand the actual meaning and their reason, not the procedure to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication by $t$ comes from the [variation of parameters](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) approach, where you can generate another solution if you have one already. The language about dimensions refers to linear algebra. There are [general theorems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44853/simplest-proof-of-dimension-of-solution-space-for-linear-odes) about the order of the linear differential equation relating to the dimension of the solution space. Your $2\times 2$ system of ODEs can be re-written as a single second-order ODE, which means you expect a solution space of dimension $2.$